# Open source, cross platform CD/DVD recording library for C++

Tags: qt, open-source, cross-platform, recording

I am looking for an Open source , free, and cross platform CD/DVD/BD recording library for C++(Qt).

Does anyone have any suggestions?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't know any, you shouldn't limit yourself to Qt (I don't think there is such a library), but look for cross-platform C/C++ libraries in general.

Comment: I know general C/C++ libraries would work too. But I thought mentioning Qt might clarify my problem more.
I will change the title if I can.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can look at k3b requirements (http://k3b.plainblack.com/requirements)
k3b is a CD/DVD recording application for kde. it uses qt for gui and a lot of other libraries as backends.

Comment: Thanks man. cdrecord/mkisofs is what I need.